# Excel autocorrecting formula by adding parenthesis - how to stop this?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Any formula in Excel I'm trying to use ends up with automatic parentheses that invalidates the formula. I enter the formula and hit enter - it updated with parentheses. For example:
`=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!A:G,3,FALSE)` becomes `=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!A:(G),3, FALSE)` and I end up with `#NAME?` error. This happens with any formula I use.

This only recently started happening and I can't find a way to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it always happen with `G` specifically, or with any column letter?

Comment: Any column letter

Comment: Which version of Excel is it, and does it happen in safe mode (hold down the Ctrl key while starting excel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when `R1C1` reference is chosen.
Go to Excel options, *Formulas* tab and untick "*R1C1 reference style*":

[image]

Comment: Yes, it was the R1C1 reference style that was causing this issue! Thank you so much! Will be reading up on what exactly R1C1 is :)

Comment: Basically R1C1 means "Row 1, Column 1" instead of A1 :)